# How to sort datatable using richfaces

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I am trying to sort datatable using richfaces. 
  cab anyone help me out in this.

Comment: you have to accept some answers (the tick below the vote counter)

Answer (score 5):

```
<rich:column sortBy="#{rowBean.propertyName}">
   ...
</rich:column>
```